# react-native FlatList is stuck when scrolling to the very bottom

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

In one the FlatList's that I have in a project, when I scroll to the very bottom, and try to scroll back up, scrolling is stuck.

If I keep trying to scroll, after a while (less than a minute), scrolling resumes.

I am testing on Android.

I read about many issues related to scrolling, but haven't seen this one.

Any clue? (I am not attaching any code, since the code is quite complex and is not different than other FlatList's that I have in this project)

Comment: show code and what are you loading in flatlist?

Comment: Thank you, but at this point I am just curious to know if anyone has seen such a thing.